# Can I use google analytics on vkontakte?

Tags: apache-flex, google-analytics, vk

I want to use Google Analytics on my [Vkontakte application](http://vkontakte.ru/app1549899) (written with Flex). [Vkontakte](http://vkontakte.ru/) does not support naturally in Google Analytics (not as [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/)) which means I can't even put the Google Analytics JS at the bottom of the page (or even use JS for that matter). What I can use is the [AS3 library](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/flashTrackingSetupFlex.html) of Google Analytics, but for some reason it reports of failed gif requests every time I use it to report on an event.

1. Is it even possible to use Google Analytics on the described environment?
2. If so, what could be the reason of the failed gif requests? Is it debugable?

**Update #1:**

After debugging the "Google Analytics for flex" source code, I got this error: `Error #2035: URL Not Found.`

**Update #2:**

It turns out to be a [known bug](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-13064) as suggested [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/Flex/Q_23500950.html). It works perfectly on IE.

**Update #3:**

It works on FF when I disable the "ABP Tracking Filter (by rick752)" filter at the "AdBlock Plus" extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, the problems I've experienced were due to FF problem as stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

One potentially relevant way to debug this: install a network monitor like Fiddler, and look at the requests going over the wire. Do you see the right GIF get downloaded? If so, you're good. If not, you'll see what's going on on the network.

Comment: The network is fine, but I can't see the requests in fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some info from Google on [debugging the gif requests](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingTroubleshooting.html). What do you mean when you say it failed?